# Что необходимо знать веб-программисту?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Вот подумываю сейчас на счет веб-программирования и хочу узнать, какой набор знаний необходим хорошему веб-программисту. Просьба описать по подробнее, подумываю над выбором этой профессии. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @ArniLand У Вас много вопросов, которые получили хорошие ответы и не были приняты. Не забывайте принимать ответы.

Comment: с чего мне стоит начать, что стоит осваивать в первую очередь? В данный момент изучаю основы программирования, по темам которые мне подсказали тут http://hashcode.ru/questions/5261/изучение-основ-программирования

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development

Answer (score 9):

- Представление о различных стандартах, протоколах: XHTML, HTML, CSS2.1, RSS, HTTP/1.1 и иные;
- Умение поиска в интернете, гугле, по документации, форумам и иным местам с полезными и не очень знаниями на русском и английском языке;
- Знание одного или нескольких серверных языков: Ruby, PHP, Perl, Python, ASP, Java;
- Знание JavaScript. Хорошее;
- Желательно хорошее знание одного или нескольких серверных и браузерных фреймворков;
- Умение разворачивать/устанавливать готовые системы;
- Умение использовать и понимать чужой код;
- Желательно понимание ОС типа *nix;
- Умение хорошо программировать;
- Понимание архитектуры клиент-сервер;
- Знание и понимание одной или нескольких баз данных и языка запросов.
- JSON, XML, AJAX - тоже бы.
- Желательно знание и понимание одной или нескольких мультимедийных платформ: Adobe Flash, Flex, Microsoft Silverlight, Java.
- Желательно знание новых стандартов и технологий: HTML5, CSS3.
- Понятие кодировки текста.

Ну, так, примерно.

Answer (score 4):

Ну это совсем простой вопрос :)

- Нужно очень хорошо владеть HTML4 и в наше время HTML5
- Нужно очень хорошо владеть CSS. В идеале хорошо бы прочесть официальную спеку по CSS. Лично я стал хорошо понимать CSS только после её прочтения.
- Необходимо хорошо знать JavaScript. Для того, чтобы писать хорошо на нём, придётся как следует разобраться с программированием как таковым, иначе вы будете писать плохой код на JavaScript, а он в свою очередь жестоко наказывает за небрежное обращение. Не помешает знание какиех-нибудь библиотек и фреймворков для JS (например, jquery, dojo, etc), но это надо делать существенно позже, а точно не в начале, иначе вы рискуете начать пользовать мощностями не понимая, как они работают
- Надо ознакомиться с тем, как работает HTTP, хотя бы поверхностно. Хотя бы поверхностно понять, как работают веб-сервера. Понять, каким образом браузер получает данные с сервера.
- Необходимо понять, какие есть способы динамического генерирования контента

После всего этого придётся принять важное решение. Придётся выбирать язык программирования для серверной части. Тут уж выбор зависит от вас и путь изучения будет зависеть от вашего выбора.

Comment: Сейчас я просто изучаю базовые основы программирования с помощью C++. А что скажете на счет PHP, Ruby, Python и что значит "серверная часть"? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что можно почитать на мою тему, чтобы иметь представление о веб программировании.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать получить компетенцию Junior Web Developer на [quizful.net](http://www.quizful.net/job-role/junior-web-developer).

Answer (score 1):

Беретесь за создание простенького сайта и там вереница сама потянется - html, css, php, mysql, регистрация домена, выкладка скриптов на сервер... главное "создавать", а не только учиться.

Comment: точняк! по css можно ничего не читать. эту фигню можно по ходу выучить, проверено!)

Answer (score 1):

- Иметь хороший стиль кода, комментировать код
- Html (Включая 5ю версию, возможно XHTML)
- CSS (включая 3ю версию)
- PHP/ASP/Pyton/Perl/Любой другой язык (на выбор, можно несколько)
- SQL (в том числе особенности для Mysql/MSSQL/Oracle/PostgreSQL/Другой БД которую будете использовать)
- JavaScript (JQuery, Ajax - как дополнение, обязательно хорошее знание DOM)

Дополнительно:

- XML
- Шаблонизаторы (Smarty/Ptal/Xtemplate/XSLT на выбор лучше несколько)
- Знание серверов (Apache, Nginx, Lighthttpd, NodeJS)
- Изучить кеширование (Как на уровне языка так и на сервере)
- JSON
- Flash/Silverlight (Необязательно, HTML5 в ближайшее время будет более востребован)
- Знания готовых продуктов (phpbb, wordpress и других, лишним не будет)

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на Node.js.
Писать нагруженные проекты на PHP возможно, но тяжело. Как правило, ценой каких то архитектурных компромиссов. Python и Ruby функционально богаче, чем PHP, но, не халивара ради скажу, не далеко от него ушли. Особенно в плане производительности.

Answer (score 0):

И js,ajax,XML,JSON,JQuery - можно выучить по ходу)) Я считаю достаточно знать html,css,php,mysql. Всё остальное придёт с опытом. Даст тебе работодатель задание натянуть сайт на WordPress/Joomla - почитаешь необходимую литературу или статью даже и натянешь. Натянешь один раз, второй, третий и для тебя это уже обычное дело. Даст тебе дядя-работодатель задачу поправить баг на сайте: тут ты и в кодировках научишься разбираться (потому что много багов с ней), и в чужом коде разбираться научишься. В общем всё будет зависеть от работодателя, насколько он будет интересные задачки давать. Ты не бойся заданий главное, если умеешь искать информацию - то всё норм будет. Мне повезло, у меня работодатель был прям как учитель, задания усложнялись постепенно)) В общем главное: html & css,php & mysql. Учить именно в таком порядке html с css, php с mysql. Если хватит терпения выучить - значит молодец. После этого советую также какой-нибудь свой проект для опыта в программировании забабахать.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно знать:

1. html
2. css
3. php
4. js
5. mysql
6. PhotoShoop (для дизайна твоих проектов - не обязательно на 100%, но если не хочешь платить другим за дизайн, не помешает)

Comment: Ваша грамматика потрясает воображение. Пишите, пожалуйста, грамотнее. Воспользуйтесь словарем или автопроверкой текста в браузере.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, такое удалить проще чем править имхо

Answer (score -1):

Для бэкенд программирования:

- Unix, git
- Генераторы документации (например Sphinx-doc)
- БД: sqlite, Postgres, Redis, MongoDB, ZODB
- OSI и TCP/IP
- клиент-серверная архитектура
- Сокеты
- HTTP
- HTML, XHTML, XML, CSS, JavaScript (на базовом уровне)
- CGI, FastCGI, WSGI
- Nginx обратный прокси и статика
- Шаблоны, ORM, request&response библиотеки, роуты, пагинация, генераторы форм и все прочее
- Фреймворки MVC->MTV->RV
- Асинхронный веб: AJAX, websocket

[Вот примерный план](http://lectureswww.readthedocs.org/) (пока как прототип)